# Is there a way to nest calls to F# active patterns?

Tags: f#

Is there a way to nest calls to active patterns?

Something like this:

```
type Fnord =
| Foo of int

let (|IsThree|IsNotThree|) x = 
  match x with
  | x when x = 3 -> IsThree
  | _ -> IsNotThree

let q n =
  match n with
  | Foo x ->
    match x with
    | IsThree -> true
    | IsNotThree -> false
  // Is there a more ideomatic way to write the previous
  // 5 lines?  Something like:
//  match n with
//  | IsThree(Foo x) -> true
//  | IsNotThree(Foo x) -> false

let r = q (Foo 3) // want this to be false
let s = q (Foo 4) // want this to be true
```

Or is the match followed by another match the preferred way to go?

Comment: The damn language is unreadable. Seriously - what can it do that Python cannot?

Comment: @lpthnc: Pattern matching?

Comment: @lpthnc: Type checking? Algebraic data types? Currying? etc etc ...
Actually, I already answered this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126790/if-you-already-know-lisp-why-would-you-also-want-to-learn-f/129402#129402

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works.  You just have the patterns backwards.

```
type Fnord =
| Foo of int

let (|IsThree|IsNotThree|) x = 
  match x with
  | x when x = 3 -> IsThree
  | _ -> IsNotThree

let q n =
  match n with
  | Foo (IsThree x) -> true
  | Foo (IsNotThree x) -> false

let r = q (Foo 3) // want this to be true
let s = q (Foo 4) // want this to be false
```

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Well, the ability to nest patterns in their main benefit over other forms of dispatch, e.g. virtual methods.