# Replace codeparts during build like the good old #define in c++ did

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators

We are looking for a way to add an NOT Operator to our solutions. Unfortunately, C# doesnt support new operators, so we couldnt just add NOT as a new Operator.

Next thing we thought of was implementing a static method NOT(). But at this moment, C# doesnt support using Namespace.StaticTypeName; (atleast we havent figured it out yet) - Thats why we would have to write down the silly classname all the time.

Then we had finally the idea to replace the NOT with the !-Operator, every time we build the solution... like the good old #define in c++.

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: C# does support operator overloading. Can you be more specific? Maybe a syntax sample?

Comment: What's wrong with *just* using the `!` operator? That would seem much more sensible to me. You can't do what you're proposing in straight C#, which I'm *very* glad about.

Comment: If you want more verbose language you could always use VB.  It has `Not` built in.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The OP is looking to create a new operator called `NOT`, not to overload the existing `!` operator.

Comment: @Jannik What exactly do you need this `NOT()` operator for?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what problem you are trying to solve because it isn't really clear right now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman VB and C# are very interchangeable in the .NET world.  I think it's a reasonable suggestion if the OP wants verbosity in the language.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: I know, but that is not adding an operator. And for that OP can use c#'s version of `Not` too.

Comment: We would like to use a NOT Operator to make high-complexitivity codeparts more readable.

Comment: And what would that operator's implementation look like? What's wrong with the existing operators? Can you use extension methods to do the same?

Comment: @just.another.programmer: Thats not an option, we are working on a program with > 1,000,000 lines of code. :)

Comment: implementation would be this: public bool NOT(bool obj)
        {
            return !obj;
        }

Comment: So what is wrong with `!obj` in the code? I think that is a lot more readable than `NOT(obj)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have preprocessing in plain old C#.

But if you're willing to create "your own C#", you can use [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) to make the transformations on the syntactic tree for you before compiling it.

An exemple of such a transformation can be seen in the [response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749222/is-there-a-way-to-implement-custom-language-features-in-c).

However, I would advise against this kind of practice: it makes your code less readable for pretty much everybody except your own team, makes your build process more complicated, requires a specific training for the people you add to your team and is likely to break most of the static analysers.

You can also achieve your result with the following:

Comment: @PatrickHofman: exactly. You can, but don't do it for such trivial things. However, DO use Roslyn as a preprocessor to automatically implement complex and repetitive logic on some classes. For instance, observable properties on ViewModels in MVVM are a pain to write on every single. Create an attribute and let Roslyn rewrie the properties for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no preprocessing in C#, so you cannot use #defines for what you want.

You can try using extension methods like this:

```
public static T Not<T>(this T) {
    // your logic here
    return ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
... || myvar.Not() + ...
```

This way you needn't to use class name where extension method is declared, but you will still need to add `using MyNamespace;` for namespace of class which contains extension method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, you cannot create new operators in C#. .NET does expose compiler classes though, so you could roll-your-own compiler that replaces these values right before processing them.

The extension method solution Lanorkin shared probably is the best if you want to keep conforming to C#. Another "solution" would be a namespace-less static `Not` class:

```
public struct Not
{
    public Not(bool value)
        : this()
    {
        NotValue = !value;
    }

    public bool NotValue
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Not value)
    {
        return value.NotValue;
    }
}

bool trueValue = new Not(false);
```

For your new hires this would also clearly show that the operator is a new one, not a C# one.

Does your entire team feel that the exclamation mark hurts readability? Do they all have a good old c++ background? How big are your `if` statements? Have you considered swapping the `if` and `else` parts to reduce the need for `not`ting in the first place?

If I would start to work for your company it would take me months to unlearn the exclamation mark.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We dont have c++ Background, but from our point of view, C#'s !-Operator isnt as readable as the SQL equivalent NOT. Even && and || are making problems in some specific cases. You're correct, in some situations, we might be able to refactor those ifs and return.. For the rest of the Statements I guess we will have to stick to the !-Operator..

Answer (score 0):

I sounds to me, after some clarification in comments, that you are on the wrong way.

Please don't try to make a function for trivial operations like `!`. This will not only clutter your code with something a new person doesn't understand, it will also cost you performance if the method isn't inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are a good way to do this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool NOT(this bool flag)
    {
        return !flag;
    }
}
```

So regardless of where you are in the code you can call someBool.NOT();

If you absolutely want to only be able to call it as NOT(someBool) then do it like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool NOT(this object ignored, bool flag)
    {
        return !flag;
    }
}
```