# In C#, is there a way for me to create a shorthand expression for defining a generic (or other type)?

Tags: c#, customization

The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`.  Is there a way I can do something similar to this, but with my own custom characters/etc.?

Like making `T!` shorthand for `MyGeneric<T>`.

Comment: Nope. You can use Roslyn to do pre-processing, but that's about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749222/is-there-a-way-to-implement-custom-language-features-in-c

Comment: No. There is feature request to allow "using" [aliases for unbounded generics](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3993).

Answer (score 0):

You can, in a sense. You are not able to use `!` because it is not a valid character for identifiers but you could use any other valid characters. That being said, this is very limited. If you know a base type that you are going to use, you can do:

```
using @c = System.Collections.Generic.List<B>;
```

Where `B` is the base class. If you want a more generic version you could do:

```
using @c = System.Collections.Generic.List<object>;
```

You could now use `@c` as if it is a `List<B>` or `List'. Such as:

```
@c a = new @c;
a.Add(new B());
```

Like I said, it is limited and not practical but it is semi-possible.

Comment: Why are you using the `@` operator for the identifier `c`?

Comment: while this is possible... I'm pretty sure if I ever came across this in code I would hunt down the dev and smack the crap out of them.

Comment: The `@` is not actually part of the identifier. You could write `c a = new c()` and have it work just as well. The `@` is simply indicates to the compiler that the token is an identifier and not to be treated as a keyword.

Comment: @Servy because the original post had unique characters in it so I figured I would show what is possible.

Comment: @MatthewWhited The premise of the question would make me do the same!

Comment: @mikez good to know. I just chose the `@` because it was something that stuck out, similar to the `!` that was used in the original post

Comment: @Jetti The use of `@` in no way allows `!` to be used in an identifier, or any other characters that wouldn't otherwise be valid in an identifier.

Comment: @Servy I understand that. I had no intention to use an invalid identifier character but was using a valid identifier character to differentiate from other identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done unless you use Roslyn. I believe the closest thing (correct me if I'm wrong) to what you want is something like this:

```
using YourAlias = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>; // or whatever type you want
```

and to use it:

```
var dict = new YourAlias();
```