# How to create a custom syntax for describing an object in c#?

Tags: c#, object, types

**Searching Effort:**

1. Google:

   - [custom c# syntax](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=custom%20c%23%20syntax)
   - [c# floating point](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+floating+point)
2. Stackoverflow:

   - [custom c# syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+c%23+syntax)
   - [c# floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+floating+point)

And some more I do not remember...

---

**Preconception:** Every "built-in type" in c# (such as `int`, `float`, `char`etc.) is a class, and every class in C# inherits from the `Object` class. Therefore, every "built-in type" inherits from the `Object` class.

With that preconception in mind, I would assume that to set a `double` variable, for example, I would need to set some properties using the "normal" syntax. Here is what I mean:

```
double number = new double();

number.leftSide= 5;
number.rightSide = 23;

Console.Write(number);

// Output:
// 5.23
```

But C# has a special, equivalent syntax for creating a `double` variable (in a way that it would do what I **tried** to do above, not that the code above will actually work):

```
double number = 5.23;
```

The compiler *understands* that the floating point separates the number into two: 5 and 23.

My question is if I can do the same with my own classes. For example, if I have my own `Time` class (and it is just an example, so please do not suggest to use built-in time classes), I would want to have the option to instantiate it like so:

```
Time time = 10:25;
```

And the compiler would understand that the colon separates the number into hours and minutes (which are, I assume, properties I need to create in the `Time` class).

I have heard about [Roslyn CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749222/is-there-a-way-to-implement-custom-language-features-in-c) but I am looking for a simpler, built-in way, of doing what I have described.

Can I do it?

Comment: general rule is few languages (Groovy) is operator forcing, Your fragment can be presented (integer 10) (operator : ) (integer 25) - but I think ':' is impossible in C#

Comment: cont .. 5.23 is at lexical level, one level below parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible in C# currently. The closest you can do is define an implicit conversion from `string` to `Date`. For example

```
public class Time
{
    public static implicit operator Time(string value)
    {
        // Initialize your object with value
        // Similar to 
        var values = value.Split(':');
        var hour = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        var min = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        . . .
    }
    . . .   // Your fields, properties and methods
}
```

This would let you

```
Time time = "10:25";
```

Comment: That is a wonderful solution! I would wait for other answers to see if they are more helpful, but if not - I would choose this one.

Comment: @Sipo This answer provides a really good way to express what you want to ultimatelly achieve. I think other answers, including mine, can just provide more background info. Personally, I'd just consider making `Time` a `struct`, not a `class`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny - Thank you vert much! If I would create `Time` as a `struct`, would I be able to do what I try to do, or I will still need @Shreevardhan's solution?

Comment: @Sipo You can define similar implicit conversion inside a `struct` also.

Comment: @Sipo You need Shreevardhan's solution.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is if I can do the same with my own classes.

No, you cannot. C# does not support user-defined syntax constructs. You have to live with the set of language features such as syntax constructs, operators, etc. defined by the language.

> Every "built-in type" in c# (such as int, float, charetc.) is a class, and every class in C# inherits from the Object class.

The primitive types (such as `int`, `float`, etc.) are *not* classes. They are primitive types. In order to support object-oriented features such as methods, the language defines `struct`s (such as `Int32`, `Single`) that 'kind of' shadow the primitive types.

The fact everything can be an `Object` is in case of primitive types achieved through boxing—a process that takes the primitive value type and creates an object 'envelope' around it.