# VSIX Extending existing C# language editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

**Background:** I want to extend the existing C# language using a VSIX-plugin with highlightning support (optional IntelliSense-support) and a custom pre-processor to allow some custom-defined syntactic sugar (e.g. new keywords, custom operators, special pre-processor constants etc).

---

I know one can create a *new* syntax editor using C# and [this MSDN Tutorial series](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx), but I am wondering, how one can extend the existing C# language editor using a VSIX-extension.

Does anyone has a link to a blog/example of such a project?

I also know, that it is possible to access the Roslyn syntax-tree using VS2015, but I am not quite sure how to use it without extending the Roslyn compiler itself (see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749422/3902603))