# Custom preprocessor directive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to create a custom preprocessor directive in C# to influence on the process of compilation? If there's no built-in support for defining a new directive, could you suggest a workaround to simulate similar behaviour?

Comment: Are you saying you want a new directive like `#doSpecalStuff` or do you mean something like `#if MY_DIRECTIVE` and you want to define `MY_DIRECTIVE`?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that. It's very hard to suggest a workaround with no clue what kind of behavioral change you're trying to make.

Comment: @scott-chamberlain, yes, you understand it completely right. I actually want to create a new directive.

Comment: @NamiraJV Okay - what do you want this new directive to do?

Comment: Then how do you expect us to give you a work around if you have not explained the behavior you want to do?

Comment: @jon-skeet, I want to make compiler generate some code depending on the directive and its parameters

Comment: So you want to have some token that means "given these parameters, do this thing". Why is a function call not appropriate here?

Comment: It sounds like either you should be writing regular code, or modifying the compiler itself. There's nothing like general purpose macros in C#.

Comment: For example, OpenMP for C/C++ uses the form of directives to provide its functionality. I was just wondering if we can implement an API in that kind of fashion.

Comment: Well, nobody's preventing you from writing your own compiler. That's how custom compilation is done. Or just use a code generator, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that in c#. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) is a list of all directives.

Alternative you maybe can work with the following directives:

You can add defines to the processor like this:

```
#define xx
```

And check for them like this

```
#if (xx)
    Console.WriteLine("xx defined");  
#else  
    Console.WriteLine("xx not defined");  
#endif
```

---

If you are working with `roslyn` take a look at this [interesting article](http://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/implementing-custom-load-behavior-in-roslyn-scripting/) but be carefull with what you do.

Or take a look at this [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749422/6583901) which shows you how to implement your custom syntax with the roslyn scripting api.

Comment: That's not what the OP is after - they're after *custom* directives, as I understand it.