# How to define constraint for generic interface where-clause

Tags: c#, .net, generics, cs0246

C# has no preprocessing and I don't want to define "struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible" for all interfaces, that need this constraint. What I need is something like:

Named constraint **"IMyItemConstraint"** for several generic interface where-clauses:

```
public interface IProperty2Enum<T>
    : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IMyItemConstraint { } // <--- here

public interface IMyCollection2<T>
    : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    where T : IMyItemConstraint { } // <--- here

public interface IMyObservableCollection2<T>
    : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    where T : IMyItemConstraint { } // <--- here
```

I tried to define a name "IMyItemConstraint", but I get errors CS####:

```
public interface IMyItemConstraint 
    : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible { } // CS1031: Type expected 

public interface IMyItemConstraint : where IMyItemConstraint
    : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible { } // CS1031: Type expected 

public interface IMyItemConstraint<T> where T // This does not help:
    : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible { }
```

Is it possible, to define a named constraint for generic interface where-clause for several interfaces (contracts)?

Comment: I would create a [Code Snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) for the boiler plate code.  Also see:[How to: Create a New Snippet with Replacements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165396.aspx).

Comment: @TnTinMn: Good idea, if you're not in a project phase of 'concept', where you want to get a decision and you want to try several variants.

Comment: If you need dynamic code generation to quickly evaluate alternatives, then it may be worth the trouble to set up a T4 template.  See: [Design-Time Code Generation by using T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx).  This is basically a pre-processing step to generate a code file.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not kow **4 Text Templates** until now.
Looking for other solutions I found **Roslyn CTP** in this answer:
[Custom language features in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749422/3303008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunutely you can't inherit generic constraints. You need to define constraints separately for each type parameter.

Comment: Thanks. :-) Are there compiler extensions or c# preprocessors available to solve this (common?) problem?

Comment: @TorstenCrull not as far as I know.

Comment: Since "**4 Text**", "**Roslyn CTP**" or other **custom specific extensions** seem to be the only solution, I accepted this answer. Thank you.