# Extending C# syntax with custom keywords and control flow

Tags: c#, clr, roslyn

I have a class `Hopefully<T>` that contains either an `error` or a `value`. Whenever a method returns one of these I need to check for errors and either handle them right there, or propagate further up the call-chain:

```
class Hopefully<T> 
{ 
   MyError Error; 
   T SomeTValue; 
   // Implicit conversion should be defined here from Error and from T
}

public Hopefuly<int> SquareRoot(int x) 
{ 
   return x >= 0 ? sqrt(x) : new MyError(...); 
}

public Hopefull<string> PrettySquareRoot(int x)
{
   var r = SquareRoot(x);     // r is Hopefully<int>
   if (r.IsError)
     return r.Error;          // r.Error is MyError
   var v = r.SomeTValue;      // v is int
   return $"the root is {v}";
}
```

I find this too verbose, and would like to write like this:

```
public Hopefull<string> PrettySquareRoot(int x)
{
   var v = assume SquareRoot(x); 
   // v is int; if callee returned error it's escalated automatically before v is assigned
   return $"the root if {v}";
}
```

Here the new `assume` keyword would check the right-side, and if it's an error it would immediately return from the method with that error. If there is no error, it would extract `SomeTValue` and assign it to `v`.

So it's similar to `await` in appearance, and similar to `exceptions` in behavior.

Compared to exception this would have better performance on millions of errors (yes, I need every one of those errors). It's also more explicit - a programmer can silently ignore exceptions but cannot do that to `Hopefully<T>` - they have to unpack the `value`.

The nearest I have found so far is this [1] but this seems a lot, and there is no information on how to integrate this into Visual Studio. I would like to hear other ideas before I dive into it.

[1] [Is there a way to implement custom language features in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749222/is-there-a-way-to-implement-custom-language-features-in-c)

Comment: No, you can't. But if you search nuget.org for "functional", you'll find plenty of libraries that have already invented this wheel and achieve a reasonably good level of comprehensibility within the C# syntax.

Comment: This sounds a lot like [Railroad Programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/)

Comment: Indeed it does, @gunr2171. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend the C# syntax. I suggest implementing a `Chain` method in the class `Hopefully<T>`

```
public Hopefully<U> Chain<U>(Func<T, U> convert)
{
    if (Error != null) {
        return Error;
    }
    return convert(SomeTValue);
}
```

Then you can write

```
public Hopefully<string> PrettySquareRoot(int x)
{
    return SquareRoot(x).Chain(v => $"the root is {v}");
}
```

Note that the type parameter of `Chain` can be inferred by C#.

---

My test implementation. I'm using [Expression-bodied members (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

```
public class MyError
{
    public MyError(string message) => Message = message;
    public string Message { get; }
}

public class Hopefully<T>
{
    public Hopefully(T value) => SomeTValue = value;
    public Hopefully(MyError error) => Error = error;

    public static implicit operator Hopefully<T>(T value) => new Hopefully<T>(value);
    public static implicit operator Hopefully<T>(MyError error) => new Hopefully<T>(error);

    public MyError Error { get; }
    public T SomeTValue { get; }

    public Hopefully<U> Chain<U>(Func<T, U> convert)
    {
        if (Error != null) {
            return Error;
        }
        return convert(SomeTValue);
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        Error != null ? $"Error: {Error.Message}" : SomeTValue.ToString();
}
```

The `SquareRoot` method

```
public Hopefully<int> SquareRoot(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0) {
        return (int)Math.Sqrt(x);
    }
    return new MyError("The argument of SquareRoot must be greater than or equal to 0");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! I though I tried this in the past, but let me try again now.